# Can you set a command for a breakpoint with !bpmd in a single line?

Tags: debugging, clr, windbg

I'd like to run a command each time my breakpoint in managed code is hit, I know how to do it in three commands.  Can it be done in one?

The way to do it in three commands is

!bpmd system.web.dll xxxx;
bl;
bp yyyy "zzz; g;"

Where yyyy is the address of xxxx which is an output of 'bl'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to set  `command` when `bp` hits then you could probably use `!mbp` or `!mbm` from [sosex](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx)  instead of using `!bpmd`